# Create jar file of java application using swing of multiple pages

Tags: java, swing, command-line, jar, javac

I want to create a jar file of my Swing application which are connected multiple pages of `JFrame`. I searched a lot about connected multiple pages of creating jar file I didn't get the correct answer. In my project folder I have more than 10 java class which are connected to each other.

**My project folder**
Login is connect to admin and employees and so on.

I have search the command of creating jar file:

`Jar cfm adm.jar login.class`

So how can I get all class and merger automatically all in adm.jar without writing each class?

Comment: Did you try `jar cfm adm.jar *.class`? **Edit:** Or more correct `jar -cfm adm.jar *.class`

Comment: Seriously, use a IDE or a decent build system to do these things

Comment: @Andrew Thompson i didn't try . Can you tell me my other pages automatically attach with my main class ?and i will try your solution asap. I am doing more research . By the way thanks

Comment: @MadProgrammer i am usinh this into my command line in my bitbucket

Comment: @vivekmodi Then consider using Ant or Maven

Comment: `printf "Main-Class: com.controller.LoginScreen\nClass-Path: mysql-connector-java.jar" >> manifest.MF`                                                                                                                                    `find com -type f \( -name '*.class' -o -name '*.jar' \) -exec jar -cvfm Newspaper.jar manifest.MF {} +`                                                                                      @AndrewThompson                                                                                                         to create jar file of swing but i get the error

Comment: When i am execute the jar file its give mysql error something like **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver**  @MadProgrammer do you have any suggestion for this

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` The `*.class` only collects all the classes in the **current directory.** *"MadProgrammer do you have any suggestion for this"* Yes, and it is *"use a IDE or a decent build system to do these things"* - at this stage, I'm tending to agree.

Comment: I am putting jar file also in jar and add classpath also so why this is not happen Any other solution for this i don't know because i am doing this in my bit bucket pipelines using bash scripts @AndrewThompson

Comment: *"I am putting jar file also in jar"* That won't work. Either the classes themselves (sans Jar) need to be in the main Jar, or alternately the Jar needs to be added to the run-time class-path.

Comment: @AndrewThompson how can you tell me or any reference to learn from there

Comment: [The jar Command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/jar.html) ..

Comment: `find src -type f -name '*.java' -exec javac -d bin -cp lib/*.jar {} +`         i am running the command with multiple jar files like junit,MySQL and hibernate library but it gives error to me **javac invalid flag in hibernate library** @AndrewThompson